# RegEx for QRadar SIEM

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a custom property for QRadar SIEM that involves Regular Expressions. Looking for the best way to match the group `Security ID` or `Account Name` which is currently populated with the `IT-TESTGRP` account. The goal is to pull out whatever account is found under `Group`. I have having a hard time figuring out a match while avoiding similar criteria found under `Subject:` & `Member:`. I only want the account associated with `Group:`

> <13>Jan 09 12:33:50 SRVDC0 AgentDevice=WindowsLog  AgentLogFile=Security   PluginVersion=7.2.4.86  Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing  Computer=SRVDC0.corp.teslab.ca  OriginatingComputer=SRVDC0  User=   Domain= EventID=4756    EventIDCode=4756    EventType=8 EventCategory=13826 RecordNumber=1244048131 TimeGenerated=1483983229    TimeWritten=1483983229  Level=0 Keywords=0  Task=0  Opcode=0    Message=A member was added to a security-enabled universal group.  Subject:  Security ID:  CORP\bforeman  Account Name:  bforeman  Account Domain:  CORP  Logon ID:  0x220f7a57  Member:  Security ID:  CORP\jsmith  Account Name:  CN=jsmith\, Dan,OU=Exchange Users,DC=corp,DC=testlab,DC=ca  Group:  Security ID:  **CORP\IT-TESTGRP**  Account Name:  **IT-TESTGRP**  Account Domain:  CORP  Additional Information:  Privileges:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is to match `group: Security ID` as done in the pattern below:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Group: Security ID: (\\w+)\\\\([^ ]+) Account Name: ([^ ]+) Account Domain: \\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Jan 09 12:33:50 SRVDC0 AgentDevice=WindowsLog AgentLogFile=Security PluginVersion=7.2.4.86 Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing Computer=SRVDC0.corp.teslab.ca OriginatingComputer=SRVDC0 User= Domain= EventID=4756 EventIDCode=4756 EventType=8 EventCategory=13826 RecordNumber=1244048131 TimeGenerated=1483983229 TimeWritten=1483983229 Level=0 Keywords=0 Task=0 Opcode=0 Message=A member was added to a security-enabled universal group. Subject: Security ID: CORPbforeman Account Name: bforeman Account Domain: CORP Logon ID: 0x220f7a57 Member: Security ID: CORP\\jsmith Account Name: CN=jsmith, Dan,OU=Exchange Users,DC=corp,DC=testlab,DC=ca Group: Security ID: CORP\\IT-TESTGRP Account Name: IT-TESTGRP Account Domain: CORP Additional Information: Privileges:");

while(m.find()){
 System.out.println("domain: "+m.group(1) +", security id: "+m.group(2)+", account Name: "+m.group(3)); 
}
```

which returns

```
domain: CORP, security id: IT-TESTGRP, account Name: IT-TESTGRP
```

In order to get rid of the group prior to the security ID just match the word before the backslash and then make sure that the word matches with the Account Domain string using back-references.

Comment: I used the following RegEx to extract the group security ID "CORP\IT-TESTGRP"  `Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+([^ ]+)`  I can't quite figure out how to properly strip the domain (CORP\\) to just match on the group name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - `Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+.*?\\([^ ]+)` - Here is my use case https://regex101.com/r/5gw5EO/1